# Pass An int value from view to Action from a link click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a for loop in my view about a table. I am able to display the results. but when i click any of the links . i get a null point exception. i found that it is because that the loop is finished

```
 @model List<MyMainModel>
@using System.Collections;
@using System.Web;
@{

    ViewData["Title"] = "Display";
}

<h1>Display</h1>
<table border="1" cellpadding="20" style="table-layout:fixed">
    <tr>
        <th>
            UserName
        </th>
        <th>
            PAssword
        </th>

        <th>
            Email
        </th>
        <th colspan="2">
            Options
        </th>
       
    </tr>
    @{ for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Model.ElementAt(i).USERNAME
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.ElementAt(i).PASSWORD
            </td>

            <td>
                @Model.ElementAt(i).EMAIL
            </td>
            <td >
               <a href="@Url.Action("RemoveRow", "MyMain")">Remove</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("EditRow", "MyMain")">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
            }
        }
</table>
```

When i click Remove i want to pass ID of the corresponding Element back to RemoveRow Action how do i do that

Comment: Where exactly does your system throw `NullReferenceException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Url.Action("RemoveRow", "MyMain", new { id = i })
```

Comment: Are you able to provide further information to help your answer?

Comment: The id is in @Model.ElementAt(i).ID but since ithe loop is complete b4 user can click remove. The value of i will become null (for loop is complete and table displayed). Do at run time i can't uniquely identify those rows